# QGIS automation field from Excel

Tags: qgis, excel, virtual-field

I present the following situation.

1 - Draw polygon shape in QGIS 3.4 / geopackage, only with two columns ID and NUM_SETOR, using the google maps image as reference.

2 - Excel table where I combine a series of parameters, making use of formulas, dropdown list and free text. At the end I import this table into the QGIS.

3 - Make a JOIN between graphical feature (1) and table (2), having as a connection the columns NUM_SETOR.

4 - Export to a new shape.

I am trying to end using Excel and its formulas, making use of only the QGIS, for example, of the commands within the properties of the layer, attributes form -> Value Relation, Value Map, Data / time, etc. , creation of virtual fields for the concatenation of other fields, etc.

The problem is that everything is linked to the project and the layers being viewed. If I create a new project and connect to the same geopackage database, I will not have anything that I intend to do.

Is this the best way? Any suggestion? Can I reproduce all excel results in QGIS?
I will try submit an example of the excel table.

Comment: Can the geopackage and project not stay paired together?  What type of variability do you have with either?

Comment: I think both (PKG and QGZ) should be together and distributed together. My question is: if someone erases a layer that is being used by another. All confiration will be lost.

Comment: Maybe keep a back up of the PKG and qgs file somewhere else if something happens to either or.

Comment: Yes, the idea is to keep both in a read-only folder. But my first question is: what is the best practice to eliminate the use of excel? It has the automated fields and I need to be able to do in QGIS a similar or better automation to what was done in Excel.

Comment: All the options you noted in your question are possible in QGIS.  "Is this the best way", well I guess that is up to opinion, experience, use case...etc.  I think you need to narrow your question more to a specific problem related to what your trying to do or what your stuck on to get more helpful feedback.